# Isotop-angular and stamp option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-isotope

I'm using [this isotop-angular](http://mankindsoftware.github.io/angular-isotope/) to build the tiles but within I also need that isotop items flow around one block, so it will be fixed on the right side.

On jquery isotop it possible to use stamp in options but how to use it here, on angular, can't find the right way.

Maybe someone faced with such a problem?

```
<div class="panel-event-container" isotope-container iso-options="{ transitionDuration: 0, animationOptions: { duration: 0 }, hiddenStyle: { opacity: 0 }, visibleStyle: { opacity: 1 }, }">
    <div class="map stamp"></div> <!-- this block should be fixed-->
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple solution

Just needed to add `stamp : '.stamp'` to `iso-options`

```
<div class="panel-event-container" isotope-container iso-options="{ transitionDuration: 0, stamp: '.stamp', animationOptions: { duration: 0 }, hiddenStyle: { opacity: 0 }, visibleStyle: { opacity: 1 }, }">
```